# R - complete.cases() cannot be performed after lapply

Tags: r

I was playing with two set of codes. The second code gave me an error, even though they both have the similar code.

Code 1:

```
dat = read.csv('Automobile_price data _Raw_.csv')
cols = c('price', 'bore', 'stroke', 'horsepower', 'peak.rpm')
dat[, cols] = lapply(dat[, cols], function(x) ifelse(x == '?', NA, x)) 
dat = dat[complete.cases(dat),]
```

Code 2:

```
dat = read.csv('Automobile_price data _Raw_.csv')
cols = c('price', 'bore', 'stroke', 'horsepower', 'peak.rpm')
vehs = dat[,cols] 
vehs = lapply(vehs, function(x) ifelse(x == '?', NA, x))
vehs = vehs[complete.cases(vehs),]
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in vehs[complete.cases(vehs), ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Isnt both the code executing the same same function? could someone explain why is it like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `vehs = lapply(vehs, function(x) ifelse(x == '?', NA, x))` will return a list (that is not a data.frame). If vehs is a data.frame prior to this then use `vehs[] = lapply(vehs, function(x) ifelse(x == '?', NA, x))` to preserve that structure.

Comment: Result of `lapply` depends of data. Use `purrr::map_df` to make sure you get a `data.frame`

Comment: @lmo, thanks for the clarification. I tried it with the suggested line and it worked.